# FreeBSD -- What package installs vidcontrol?

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to use the `vidcontrol` utility to change VT on FreeBSD 13.0-RELEASE, but it doesn't do anything. After roughly an hour of tryingto find out why, I had a look at the executable and it's just a shell script that does nothing.

```
kettle in ~$ cat /usr/sbin/vidcontrol
#!/bin/sh
exit 0
```

Where can I get the actual `vidcontrol`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vidcontrol(1)` is part of the base operating system in FreeBSD, and thus is not part of any package.  It appears that something or someone clobbered your file to make it a no-op.

You can retrieve the `vidcontrol` binary from the `FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-*.iso` file that you installed from (perhaps on a USB stick or optical media).  If you no longer have convenient access to the installation media you used, downloading the `bootonly` ISO will suffice:

```
$ ftp anonymous@ftp3.freebsd.org
Trying 204.15.11.115:21 ...
Connected to ftp.geo.freebsd.org.
220 This is ftp0.tuk.freebsd.org - hosted at MetaPeer http://www.metapeer.com
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230-
230-This is ftp0.tuk.FreeBSD.org, graciously hosted by ZI IN A LOCATION TBD.
230-
230-FreeBSD files can be found in the /pub/FreeBSD directory.
230-
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd /pub/FreeBSD/releases/ISO-IMAGES/13.0/
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> get FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso
local: FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso remote: FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||60919|)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso (363548672 bytes).
100% |***************************************************************************|   346 MiB   84.58 MiB/s    00:00 ETA
226 Transfer complete.
363548672 bytes received in 00:04 (83.59 MiB/s)
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

Then use `tar(1)` to identify and extract the file you need:

```
$ tar tvf FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso | grep vidcontrol
-r-xr-xr-x  1 0      0       28456 Apr  9 00:26 usr/sbin/vidcontrol
-r--r--r--  1 0      0        6154 Apr  9 00:26 usr/share/man/man1/vidcontrol.1.gz
```

I will presume that your `/tmp` directory does not contain a file or directory `/tmp/usr`.  If it does, set it aside temporarily or `rm -rf` it.

```
$ tar xpf FreeBSD-13.0-RELEASE-amd64-bootonly.iso -C /tmp usr/sbin/vidcontrol
```

Finally, inspect `/tmp/usr/sbin/vidcontrol` and try running it.  If it looks good, move it into `/usr/sbin`:

```
$ sudo chown root:wheel /tmp/usr/sbin/vidcontrol
$ sudo mv /tmp/usr/sbin/vidcontrol /usr/sbin/
```

There are some additional steps that could be taken out of an abundance of caution, such as verifying the `sha256` of the ISO file before you extract from it, but that's the gist of the process.

Comment: Thank you. I was worried I might have to reinstall entirely, I'll use the bootonly image. Also, I have never used the ftp utility (thanks to nautilus) but I should be alright.

Comment: Wait, your computer downloaded it in 4 seconds?!